# How do I call MySQL stored procedures from Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, stored-procedures

How do I call MySQL stored procedures from Perl? Stored procedure functionality is fairly new to MySQL and the MySQL modules for Perl don't seem to have caught up yet.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL stored procedures that produce datasets need you to use Perl DBD::mysql 4.001 or later. (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=609098)

Below is a test program that will work in the newer version:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure Foo(x int)
  -> begin
  ->   select x*2;
  -> end
  -> //

perl -e 'use DBI; DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=bonk", "root", "")->prepare("call Foo(?)")->execute(21)'
```

But if you have too old a version of DBD::mysql, you get results like this:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: PROCEDURE bonk.Foo can't return a result set in the given context at -e line 1.
```

You can install the newest DBD using CPAN.

Answer (score 5):

There's an example in the [section on Multiple result sets in the DBD::mysql docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#MULTIPLE_RESULT_SETS).

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Stored Proc - Multiple Values In, Multiple Out
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:RTPC;host=db.server.com',
    'user','password',{ RaiseError => 1 }) || die "$!\n";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL storedProcedure(?,?,?,?,@a,@b);');
$sth->bind_param(1, 2);
$sth->bind_param(2, 1003);
$sth->bind_param(3, 5000);
$sth->bind_param(4, 100);
$sth->execute();
my $response = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
print Dumper $response . "\n";
```

It took me a while to figure it out, but I was able to get what I needed with the above. if you need to get multiple return "lines" I'm guessing you just...

```
while(my $response = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    print Dumper $response . "\n";
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should be probably connect through the DBI library and then you should use bind variables. E.g. something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
            $ConnStr,
            $User,
            $Password,
            {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0}
          ) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
my $sql = qq {CALL someProcedure(1);}    } 

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
eval {
  $sth->bind_param(1, $argument, SQL_VARCHAR);
};
if ($@) {
 warn "Database error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 $dbh->rollback(); #just die if rollback is failing
}

$dbh->commit();
```

Mind you i haven't tested this, you'll have to lookup the exact syntax on CPAN.

Comment: You forgot the semicolon after eval {}. It's a common bug.

Answer (score 1):

*Hi, similar to above but using SQL exec.  I could not get the CALL command to work.  You will need to fill in anything that is within square brackets and remove the square brackets.*

```
   use DBI;
   #START: SET UP DATABASE AND CONNECT
   my $host     = '*[server]*\\*[database]*';
   my $database = '*[table]*';
   my $user     = '*[user]*';
   my $auth     = '*[password]*';

   my $dsn = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database";
   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $auth, { RaiseError => 1 });

   #END  : SET UP DATABASE AND CONNECT
   $sql = "exec *[stored procedure name]* *[param1]*,*[param2]*,*[param3]*;";
   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```