# Perl Dbi and stored procedures

Tags: perl, stored-procedures, dbi

How can i retrive the return value of stored procedure  by using perl and the dbi against sql server ?
could someone provide example.

Comment: I answered this in another area.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64200/how-do-i-call-mysql-stored-procedures-from-perl

Answer (score 8):

There are examples in DBD::ODBC t/ dir (see 20SqlServer.t). Basically you do (not a full working example):

```
my $output;
my $input = 'fred';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q/{ ? = call myproc(?) }/);
$sth->bind_param_inout(1, \$output, 100);
$sth->bind_param(2, $input);
$sth->execute
```

Now $output should contain whatever your procedure returned. Make sure you set then length in bind_param_inout sufficiently (the 100 above).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about SQL sproc out parameters so +1. (-: This isn't explaining how to retrieve the return value of a sproc.

Comment: I don't understand how this is not explaining how to obtain the return value of the procedure. The "? = " is the return value i.e., if you were to end the procedure (assuming returning a value from a proc is supported by the database) with return XXX then the first placeholder is the return value. The above example could be a function (which in all dbs returns a value) and the first placeholder would be the return value. You need to define what you think is a return value with an example.