# How to execute stored procedure in perl?

Tags: perl, sybase

How to execute sybase stored procedure** "**dbo.xyz**" in perl script?

```
my $procedure = "call dbo.GetAllBooks";
my $ExecProc = $dbh -> prepare($procedure) or die "Unable to prepare '$procedure'";
$ExecProc -> execute();

while (@data = $ExecProc->fetchrow_array)
     {
         open (FH, ">>Output.csv") or die "Could not open file Output.csv: $!";
         print FH "@data $csv_record .\n";;
         close (Output.csv);
     }
```

Comment: Is this the right way to save database result to .csv file in perl?

Comment: How does connection string looks? What `GetAllBooks` returns?

Comment: This will open, append and close the file for each row of results. It is very inefficient. You should put the `open` and `close` commands outside of your `while` loop. Also, use three-argument open and lexical filehandles: `open my $fh, '>>', 'Output.csv'` and `print $fh "string"`. What is `$csv_record` for? Does your code work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64200/how-do-i-call-mysql-stored-procedures-from-perl and http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=390053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like this:

```
my $sql = qq{ BEGIN  SCHEMA_NAME.STORED_PROC_NAME(); END;};
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)  || die $sth->$DBI::errstr;
$sth->execute  || die $sth->errstr; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `DBI` and `DBD::Sybase`, stored procedures are handled exactly the same way as executing any other SQL statement. There is one difference in that it will also return an extra result set for the return status. You can check the value of `$sth->{ syb_result_type }` to see if it is `CS_STATUS_RESULT` while calling the `fetch*` methods.

`DBD::Sybase` is a bit weird compared to other database drivers however. Some things may be just too difficult given the DB-Library that Sybase provides for developers so I personally don't blame the author for implementing the driver this way. `DBD::Sybase` is still done really well though.

You should definitely take some time to read the stored procedure section of the documentation in CPAN since it describe what it does and does not do. Actually, grab a cup of coffee and read all of it. I've done a good amount of work using `DBD::Sybase` and it has really helped me out.

[Calling Stored Procedures in DBD::Sybase](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::Sybase#Calling-Stored-Procedures)

Comment: @ amesee : Rather the way I implemented is, 
$varible = "exec [procedure name]";

& used DBI module